# Quines that print what their index is

Tags: code-golf, printable-ascii, self-referential

We all know what a quine is. A quine is a program which prints its own source code. And we also know about the printable ASCII characters. Well... this challenge mixes both.

Your mission, should you accept it, is to create an *index quine*. An index quine is a non-empty program, composed only of the printable ASCII characters, which prints its own *index*.

The index of a string is its position within an infinite dictionary where all strings composed of exactly the printable ASCII characters appear, sorted by size then ASCII code.

The index is a non-negative whole number, assigning 0 to the empty string then continuing with the space, !, " onward.

For example, `*!` precedes `**` as the ending `!` in the first string has lower ASCII code than the ending `*` in the second, but both are preceded by `{`, which has a higher ASCII code than the characters of the last two examples, but is shorter.

The printed index should be in base 10, outputted through STDOUT or closest equivalent, with no other output unless your language requires trailing newlines/other characters. Also, a bit like actual quines, do not access your source code directly (as a file, etc.)

Your program should be non-empty, as a reminder to those reading these rules.

If there are multiple programs of shortest length, the tiebreaker is the program with the lower index.

The shortest program following these very rules wins. Have fun.

Comment: I think you mean sorted by size then ascii code, or else some strings don't have finite index. (Actually, maybe I'm just interpreting "then" differently)

Comment: @xnor I had to double check that for a moment, since in order to "sort by size then ascii code", in practice, I'd sort by ascii code first, then sort by size, using a stable sort. :)

Comment: Yeah, I can see it both ways now. I was thinking that to sort, you first compare size, and if those are unequal, then you look at ascii value.

Comment: @Arnauld [Here](https://tio.run/##NYrBCoMwEAXv@Yp33I1YbMWDgl9SPAimbUA2YePFi7@eRsTbMDNx335B2pwTRoTohBp@qJsXYiNFNeYTFB5eoLN8Ha1lScyDgaAa0XewtnQLCrpQel8ddXE1ntNJ7YtR3aeJ6mUj4ZyPPw) is the new program to get the *index*.

Comment: If the code is required to print its own index and be a quine, does that not mean that the code can only consist of some run of the digits 0-9?

Comment: @Dingus I think the question's definition of *index quine* is meant to be entirely separate from that of a standard quine.

Comment: @mathjunkie I suspect you're right. But then why call it a quine? A program that prints its own index is a more correct description, isn't it?

Comment: @Dingus A quine shouldn't read its own source code.

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLuxoa6l6blN///XKQIA) is another program to get the index.

Comment: There *must* be a language where a space outputs 1. I tried to find one, but couldn't. TIO's interpreter for FRACTRAN outputs 2 for a space :( Retina outputs 1 for an empty program, but a space is significant in regex, so a space outputs 0.

Comment: "Quine" on this site has [some complications](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4878/78410). (TL;DR: a proper quine should have "data" and "code" sections clearly visible.) If you don't want that, you can use [tag:self-referential] instead.

Comment: Could you some example programs with their indexes?

Comment: And [here](https://tio.run/##ZZDBbtswDIbPyVMEBgLIaLuRlEiKGPwW22nYCsdxPKWpndnesK3os2fsYaedJP4i//@j5tulHOZ2/h2G52t9W9a5jMPjaZ6eH8t47H81px9jt5ZpDKV@2W6OTdeXi7eEyzSEcof3h3bpG@O63m6W5mffrdMcqu5bO7fd2s@VyydXzrsy7pb@ezjWD1jvXp6adnl3KMOf4KNfzx@Wz8eH85emjOvH6dN6ysGfveiHfg5l/37/tN8b30Ws69ftpmvXcG2XtYew3HfT5dJenaGqnOH1/w3Cv6QqAqhiNpSICIjM4AUrxWSUGQ1TkpyAGGPMopQMWATM1ShmDCiQUrKckaIRm6EpZDAxn1aXQTRmUkFVi95JSAycSMRSZPWrKWFSMk3p7eSk7O1CHJ1AibzJMBM5qluLEKoAvCVyksjuJCrsEUDIzhrJDRwH0NybJWUHYvfXLBmzcvS9DMhSzk7ue1F0OEN1BDcGNccQyOo4ABESI3mKI2FMCP6rt78) is a 'check' to get the original program back from the index.

Comment: Take a moment to wonder at how crazy a bf answer would be... (If it exists)

Comment: BF has comments in the form of using any non-instruction, which makes it marginally easier. The real difficulty is doing this in something like ///...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### [Deorst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Deorst), 1 byte

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f9f4f9/AA)

### [Commentator](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Commentator), 1 byte

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU3NK0ksyS/6/1/h/38A)

### [Snails](https://github.com/feresum/PMA), 1 byte

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85LzMwp/v9f4f9/AA)

---

So far, I have found three one-byte solutions, all of which print 1 with a space in the source code.

The first two languages were created by [@cairdcoinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing), and the last one by [@feersum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30688/feersum).

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 52 bytes

```
echo-95x#.31-3 u:(,quote)'echo-95x#.31-3 u:(,quote)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctLCsIAEATRqwRcqGBk/t3jdSQgboJgILeP0b1Qu0c9t226P@axcz1cXUcfltvp8lrm93Q@/pffNKRWozTd2WhouESgqZqVaTC2E4gSJpvQvQrREgjMwyuKTIha7RQmtTNo9V3aHUgTrtsH)

#### How it works

```
echo-95x#.31-3 u:(,quote)'echo-95x#.31-3 u:(,quote)'
                         '...'  NB. a string literal
                 (,quote)       NB. concatenate self with single-quoted self
             3 u:  NB. convert to Unicode codepoints
          31-      NB. subtract from 31 (negation of 1-based index)
     95x#.         NB. convert from base 95 to integer (using extended integer)
    -              NB. negate
echo               NB. print with newline
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>39</s> <s>37</s> 33 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Mukundan

```
hiR95]m-Cd31jN B"hiR95]m-Cd31jN B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyMzyNI0NlfXOcXYMMtPwUkJXeD/fwA)

```
hiR95]m-Cd31jN B"...
                "...   ( String literal
               B       ( Wrap in an array and duplicate
            jN         ( Join using `"` (this gives us the full source code)
      m-Cd31           ( For each character, take its codepoint minus 31
     ]                 ( Wrap in an array
 iR95                  ( Map base 95-conversion to that array
h                      ( Take the first (only) element
```

Comment: -2 byes by using ` B` instead of `*2[`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1gvVSvO0jRb1znJ2DA@y0/BSQlT6P9/AA "Pyth – Try It Online")

Comment: @Mukundan Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>82</s> <s>66</s></sup> 63 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @dingledooper

```python
exec(a:='g=0\nfor i in b"exec(a:=%r)"%a:g=g*95+i-31\nprint(g)')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVkj0cpWPd3WICYvLb9IIVMhM08hSQkmoVqkqaSaaJVum65laaqdqWtsGJNXUJSZV6KRrqmu@f8/AA)

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVkj0cpWPd3WICYvLb9IIVMhM08hSQkmoVqkqaSaaJVum65laaqdqWtsGJNXUJSZV6KRrqmu@f8/AA) using a b-string.

Comment: @dingledooper Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 471 bytes

```cs
using System.Numerics;class A{static void Main(){var s="using System.Numerics;Class A{{static void Main(){{var s={0}{1}{0};System.Console.Write(V(string.Format(s,(char)34,s)));}}static BigInteger V(string s){{BigInteger r=0;for(int i=0;i<s.Length;++i)r+=(s[i]-31)*BigInteger.Pow(95,i);return r;}}}}";System.Console.Write(V(string.Format(s,(char)34,s)));}static BigInteger V(string s){BigInteger r=0;for(int i=0;i<s.Length;++i)r+=(s[i]-31)*BigInteger.Pow(95,i);return r;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tc7BSgMxEAbgVxl6StxtaKkeJO6hLQiCiiDoQTyEGLcD3QRmZiuy5NnXHFb0UDwIvQzDwPfP73nuE4Vx7BljC4@fLKEz930XCD1bv3fMsB5YnKCHQ8I3uHMYlR4OjoCb2XG3ndwxOMlhkYdlLtNOeJsip30wz4QS1JNioRJtrhN1ThTXyu8c6dV5zVprm/MUvcH2JkpoA8G3AS5fft2pWdj3RAqjAJYdr9jchtjKzlYVaqoaxS/4Ol8t9dkPMw/pQ11e1KgtBekpApWvOc/@WfjvvieqO45f)

This is the basic C# quine with the scoring function built in. Is my scoring function a little off? It doesn't quite agree with the Python one linked in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 15 bytes

```
"r3lMF`_*+fs-|h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X6nIOMfXLSFeSzutWLcm47@hhaWBkZGxmZmRobmhqYmJkaGxqZmxpZGZuYWF8X8A)

An extension from [my own 6-byte quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160994/78410).

#### How it works

```
"r3lMF`_*+fs-|h
"...             Start string ("), push all characters, and end string(")
 r3              Reverse the stack and push 3 (= 34 - 31)
   lMF       |   Loop (stack length - 1) times...
      `_*+         [... n2 n1] -> [... n2+n1*95]
          fs-      Subtract 31
                 equivalent to "-31 from each except top and base 95 convert"
              h  Print the top number and halt
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> 65 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @Mukundan*

```python
x="g=0\nfor i in'x=%r;exec x'%x:g=95*g+ord(i)-31\nprint g";exec x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8JWKd3WICYvLb9IIVMhM0@9wla1yDq1IjVZoUJdtcIq3dbSVCtdO78oRSNTU9fYMCavoCgzr0QhXQmq6P9/AA)

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8JWKd3WICYvLb9IIVMhM0@9wla1yDq1IjVZoUJdtcIq3dbSVCtdO78oRSNTU9fYMCavoCgzr0QhXQmq6P9/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online") by using a for loop instead of the reduce

Comment: @Mukundan That’s great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + GMP, <s>156</s> 116 bytes

or [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY/LboMwEEXX@CsQEdK4gTYUISUgd999uqrayDGGmIdN7aGqivh26n2WXcxi7jzuuXbTbNmi9IVXyGZsjmfzqhE4TfOscvMI7TiVJXePV9X@wqmgn5A9F@WBPgjIE0x8UfrP820lmuxCcZOiL4lDq3R7aawZL0rX8oc1sxaojAZFFxLUTEg1@BUYTAtqnyVX7iTzvykJHPuWAo2FSNy45QKljbzceKULlQ6d/IKaphkNl57dsXWVe6/T7oMpjWfz5uOAH/tGttKCip/iPo5PxT7PKF1JMHGH8gAuEWYY@OQhIm@2EsER7lKA9nzbHw) in R

```r
"->a;t=utf8ToInt(a)-31;sum(as.bigz(95)^(115:0)*c(3,t,3,t))"->a;t=utf8ToInt(a)-31;sum(as.bigz(95)^(115:0)*c(3,t,3,t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY9PT4QwEMXP9FMQDMmMC7qEkLhL6t37ejK6KaWw5U@LbTEq4bNjvZnszcMc5uXNvN8z2yArw8wXtOOERNFli9JHVjo6u@bhpJ@UA4ZpnpV2HoHZu0q233Ao8A2yrDju8ZZDnrjED@L/L7eVKHIT8ovg/ZFYZ6Rqz43R41mqWnzSZlbcSa1A4kKCmnIhB2@BQbcgd1lSMSuo/40ksPRDcKcNRPzCDONOmMjLjVe6UKrQineoMc0wXHr6F6sr7Uuddq9UKnfSz77EL7VfRCsMyPg@7uP4UOzyDHElwcSsE3uwCdfDwCafH/mclXDm4KoAKI@2/QA)

*Edit: Big improvement by re-arranging to start immedidately with quoted string, which really simplifies the re-construction of the full program text.*

<s>This seems horribly uncompetitive, but I don't seem to be able to do any better, I'm afraid.</s>  The enormously-verbose `utf8ToInt()` function name isn't really helping much.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 724 bytes

```java
import java.math.*;class D{public static void main(String[]a0){char q=34;String s="import java.math.*;class D{public static void main(String[]a0){char q=34;String s=;String u=s.substring(0,82)+q+s+q+s.substring(82);BigInteger n=new BigInteger(s.substring(60,61));for(int i=0;i<u.length();)n=n.add(new BigInteger(new Long(95).toString()).pow(i).multiply(new BigInteger(new Long(u.charAt(u.length()-i++-1)-31).toString())));System.out.print(n);}}";String u=s.substring(0,82)+q+s+q+s.substring(82);BigInteger n=new BigInteger(s.substring(60,61));for(int i=0;i<u.length();)n=n.add(new BigInteger(new Long(95).toString()).pow(i).multiply(new BigInteger(new Long(u.charAt(u.length()-i++-1)-31).toString())));System.out.print(n);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZBNT8MwDIb/SrRTTNeoZTCBQg8gLkjcdkQcsra0Lm2SNc6madpvLykT2obgxpGDZfuR/fqjUWsVG1vqpngfBuys6Yk1AYpOUS0uZN4q59jjzvplizlzpCi4tcGCdQo1X1CPunp5VQns8lr1bJXNruSBMpdN/l7yK/KZE84v3WfGk@nNJUSryI12wgOVD1g9aSqrsmc60@WGHQE/rZ0n03kKIN9Mz1ETwyyReOdFW@qKag4SQrtQRcG/iYzpswkKt9cgyBwW5ADCmg1HEJ1vCW27/bXPi/HQe@LHYTFGUZxCPEvPJMN6i62jshPGk7CBEtcg9/vJ/19@/MswfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 34 bytes

1-byte difference with Pyth, since I can't get rid of the prepending quote in Stax.

```
"c34|Ss+{31-m95|E"c34|Ss+{31-m95|E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JrPj/XynZ2KQmuFi72thQN9fStMYVQ@D/fwA)

### Explanation

```
"..."                 The second half of the program
     c                Copy this operand
      34|S            Surround it with quotes
          s+          Prepend the quoted string with the original string
            {   m     Map: (Since direct - removes items)
             31-      Codepoint - 31 (Stax strings consist of codepoints)
                 95|E Convert from base 95
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 bytes

```
0|?F31-s94*+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=0%7C%3FF32-s94*%2B&i=)

Note that this uses the `|?` program source operand, which may be cheating

```
0   # Push a zero to the stack
|?  # Return program's source as a string
F   # for each character (as an ascii value)...
31- # subtract 31 from the character's value
s   # get the running total
94* # multiply it by 94
+   # add the character's value
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-Mbigint -M5.10.0`, 71 bytes

```perl
$_=q($n+=(95**(70-$-++))*(-31+ord)for"\$_=q($_);eval"=~/./g;say$n);eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rZQQyVP21bD0lRLS8PcQFdFV1tbU1NLQ9fYUDu/KEUzLb9IKQaiLF7TOrUsMUfJtk5fTz/dujixUiUPIvT//7/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@SZnpmXklQIapnqGBngEA)